# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 - Laravel

Tags: laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALZV5.png)

I am getting an error upon registration. I use laravel 7. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

Comment: `role_id` does not exist in your user table.

Comment: And what's your quesiton about this? Can you share more details? The given migration does not contain any details about using the registration

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `role_id` value is either missing or that the `role_id` column you want the data to insert is not present in your `users` table

Comment: what should I do? Sorry, I am just a newbie with Laravel.

Comment: can you show the code where you are doing the insert?

Comment: here is the link to my code: https://gitlab.com/janamirxavier/register-iojobs/-/blob/master/register-iojobs.txt

Comment: thats only the view, the insert is happening in your registercontroller

Comment: here is the register-controller:  https://gitlab.com/janamirxavier/controller-register/-/blob/master/register-controller.txt

Comment: So the problem is that you want to insert the value into the `role_id` column but your `users` table doesn't have this column. You will have to create this column in your migration first. Do you use some Role/Permission package or doing it by yourself?

Comment: I already added a roles id to the user's column. What do you mean "use some Role/Permission package or doing it by yourself?"

Answer (score 0):

I think you have `role_id` in your User table and if you have `role_id` in your table use the below inside your migration and if you do not have `role_id` then remove that field from your registration form.

**User Migration File**

```
$table->bigInteger('role_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
```

**User Model**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    //---Include role_id here also
    'role_id'
    'password',
];
```

Comment: I have the role_id in my user model already.

Comment: Then put that `role_id` field also in your migration.